# ExecutorService does not work but individually creating threads work

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a REST API where I am supposed to fetch large amount of data from an external API. I decided to try multi-threading to optimize the whole fetch-parse-persist cycle. But I am facing trouble with `ExecutorService` (I have not used it prior to this work). I am sharing the classes and relevant part of whole process

```
    public class LogRetrievingService implements Runnable {
    CustomHttpClient client;
    public LogRetrievingService(CustomHttpClient client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Response response = client.invokeExternalApi();
        parse(response.readEntity(bytes[].class);
    }
//skipping parse() for brevity, it basically selects some columns and sends them to DBwriter
```

My REST API resource is like this

```
public class LogRetrieverResource {
private CustomHttpClient client;

public LogRetrieverResource(CustomHttpClient client) {
            this.client = client;
}

//this does not work
public void initLogRetrieval() {
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); //max_thread 
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {            
        service.submit(new LogRetrievingService (client));
    }
}

//THIS WORKS
public void initLogRetrieval() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {            
        Thread thread = new Thread(new LogRetrievingService(client));
        thread.start();
    }
}
}
```

Now when I hit my resource nothing happens, I can see that client's logs are hit but it does not go and fetch the data.
However if inside the loop of my `LogRetrieverResource` class I create a new `Thread` instance with same run method then multithreaded data fetching works as expected. Could someone point me in what am I doing wrong? I have no prior experience of using multithreading in java other than implementing the `Runnable` interface method.

edit: Adding client class details

```
import javax.ws.rs.client.Client;
public class CustomHttpClient {

public Response invokeExternalAPI() {
return client
    .target("url") //removing url for confidentiality
    .request()
    .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    .cookie("SSO",<token>)
    .get();

}
}
```

Comment: In the second example you run those runnables in the main (request) thread, no multithreading involved there.

Comment: @michalk Thanks for your input, I cannot copy paste from my IDE due to confidentiality reasons so I made a typo. I have fixed the typos in edits. I basically want to understand if my approach of using ExecutorService in a REST API is flawed? I am using ExecutorService for the first time. Thanks for your input.

Comment: When updating your questions in the future, please do not edit the question in a way that invalidates answers you already have received. These questions and answers are meant to be useful to other people who visit the site, not just to you. If somebody responds to something that you did wrong in your example, and then you edit the example to correct the mistake, it only sows confusion. If the answer was correct, but not complete (i.e., did not solve your problem) then it's better to append an "update" to the end of your question showing what you tried, and explaining why you still need help.

Comment: @SolomonSlow Thanks, I will ensure it in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just trying to notice the differences, and there shouldn't be much difference. First at the end of your executor submission loop add `service.shutdown()`. Then you will pretty much be doing exactly the same thing.

The next issue, exceptions are handled a bit differently. An executor service will capture all of the exceptions. For debugging purposes you can try.

```
service.submit(
    () -> {
        try{
          new LogRetrievingService (client).run();
        } catch(Exception e){
        //log the exception so you can see if anything went wrong.
        }
     });
```

This is not the way to handle exceptions with an ExecutorService though, you should grab the future that you submitted and use that to handle any errors. Also, I suspect spring has some tools for doing this type of work.

Comment: Hi, your code-snippet helped me in finding the cause of error. My SSO cookie was not getting generated properly within the individual threads. My code works now.Thank you so much.